# linkage of function with parameter from unnamed namespace

Tags: c++, linkage, unnamed-namespace

```
namespace { class A { } ; }

void foo ( A ) // _Z3fooN12_GLOBAL__N_11AE
{ ; }
```

the function's symbol, apparently, would refer to the name of A, which is a member of uniquely named namespace (due to [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.unnamed#1)).

what is the foo's linkage.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `foo` has external linkage since it is global and not declared `static`. The linkage of a function doesn't depend on the parameters.

The fact that `A` has internal linkage implies that it is not possible to call `foo` from another translation unit, since it is impossible to declare `foo` in the other translation unit, since there is no way to write the name of the type of `foo`'s parameter. Any attempt to define `A` in another translation unit will actually define a different type.

Therefore, while the name `foo` technically has external linkage, it cannot actually be referred to by other translation units.